# Trigger - Collection - List Question

Tags: list, collection

I'm working on this trigger:

```
trigger ActivityCostInvitees on Event (after update){

    List<EventRelation> whoRelations = [SELECT Id, Relation.Name, Status
                                          FROM EventRelation
                                         WHERE Event.Status_Event__c ='Completed' 
                                           AND EventId IN: Trigger.old];

    List<Id> userId = new List<Id>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){

            for(Integer i=0; i<whoRelations.size(); i++) {
                if(!whoRelations.IsEmpty()){
                    userId.add(whoRelations[i].Relationid);
                }else {
                    System.assert(false);
                }
            }

            List<User> finalUsers = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Country 
                                       FROM User 
                                      WHERE Id IN : userId];
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that the **'finalUsers'** contains two users. These users have different titles and are from different countries. I want to first know the Country of each of the users and the Title of each user. Based on that I will do some further calculations. 
Anyone?Thanks in advanced!

14-05-2014

Thank you for your replies. 
I think that maybe I was not clear enough on my question. Apologies :( ... I will try to put it on a different way.

I have make some modifications. I added the **Rate__c** amount field on the User detail page.
The field **Rate__c** is just a formula that will assign a correct amount to the user by looking the Country and the Title.
So that is great because I can save some code in my trigger. Now, the question is how do I sum the amount for each of the users inside the **finalUsers** list?

If I have 3 users in the **finalUsers** list how can I access each **Rate__c** for each user and sum the to get a total rate amount?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, this should be changed:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Integer i=0; i<whoRelations.size(); i++) {
            if(!whoRelations.IsEmpty()){
                userId.add(whoRelations[i].Relationid);
            }else {
                System.assert(false);
            }
        }

        List<User> finalUsers = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Country 
                                   FROM User 
                                  WHERE Id IN : userId];
    }
}
```

to

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
{
  for (EventRelation relation: whoRelations)
  {
    userId.add(relation.RelationId);
  }

  List<User> finalUsers = [SELECT Name, Title, Activity_Rate__c, Country FROM User WHERE Id IN :userId];
  Integer userSize = finalUsers.size();
  Decimal totalRate = 0;
  for (User curr: finalUsers)
  {
    Decimal userRate;

    if (curr.Country != 'US')
    {
      userRate = curr.Activity_Rate__c
    } else if (curr.Title == 'Territory Manager')
    {
      userRate = 12.50;
    } else if (curr.Title == 'Some other title')
    {
      userRate = someOtherVal;//Fill in the blanks here
    }

    totalRate += userRate;
  }
  //After your loop, totalRate will have the correct value between all of the users
}
```

EDIT:  You could still potentially run into issues if multiple events are being updated at the same time.  It could throw off data and you might need to use a Map to switch between the associations.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
for(User usr: finalUsers)
{
    if(usr.Country=='China')
        dosomething();
    if(usr.Title=='SomeTitle')
        dosomethingelse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It may-or-may not wor as it was wrote in Notepad++ :)

```
trigger ActivityCostInvitees on Event (after update){
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        List<EventRelation> whoRelations = [SELECT  RelationId 
                                            FROM    EventRelation
                                            WHERE   Event.Status_Event__c ='Completed' 
                                                    AND  EventId IN: Trigger.old];
        if(whoRelations.IsEmpty()){
            return; // I don't understand why you use Assert so I replaced it
        }

        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();

        for(EventRelation er : whoRelations){
                userIds.add(er.Relationid);
        }

        if(userIds.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        List<User> users = MyClass.methodThatDoesSomething([SELECT Id, Name, Title, Country FROM User WHERE Id IN : userIds]);
        update users;
    }
}
```

and class

```
public class MyClass{
    public static User methodThatDoesSomething(User[] users){
        for(User usr : users){
            if(usr.Country == 'something'){
                if(usr.Title == 'somethingElse'){
                    /** do Something **/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  One thing you might want to keep in mind, that if there are multiple Events going on here, it will tally up the value for ALL events.  You would need to add additional logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

We have the finalUsers list:

`List<User> finalUsers = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Country, Activity_Rate__c
                          FROM User
                          WHERE Id IN  : userId];`

So after adding the **Rate__c** field on the user detail page I can get those values from the user list **finalUsers**.
This is from the developer console. What I do is:

```
`for(User u: finalUsers){
    if(u.Country != 'US'){ //US use combinations between Title and Country to get different rate. 

    Decimal userRate;
    Integer userSize;
    Decimal totalRate;

    userSize = finalUsers.size();
    userRate = finalUsers[0].Activity_Rate__c;
    totalRate = userRate * userSize;

    System.debug('This is the user rate: ' + userRate);
    System.debug('The total rate that is number of users multiply for user rate is :' + totalRate);
    }

}`
```

I use the `u.country != 'US'` because in our requirements US users are using a different logic. All others are using the same rate in relation to their country.
Because the **finalUsers**, at this point, will never be empty I can use the line **`userRate = finalUsers[0].Activity_Rate__c;`**. On those countries with equal **Rate__c** for their users this will be easy. Like I said at this stage if we reach the **finalUser** and the **Country** is not US, we will have at least one user in our **finalUser** list. This will stop getting any "list out of bounds error".

For US users then all I did was this, (Developer Console):

```
 List<User> territoryManagerUS = [SELECT Id, Country, Title, Activity_Rate__c 
                                  FROM User 
                                  WHERE Title ='Territory Manager' 
                                  AND Id IN : finalUsers];
 if(!territoryManagerUS.isEmpty()){

     Decimal userRateTM;
     Integer userSizeTM;
     Decimal totalRateTM;    

     userSizeTM = territoryManagerUS.size();
     userRateTM = 12.50;
     totalRateTM = userRateTM * userSizeTM;

System.debug('The number of user with title Territory Manager are: ' + territoryManagerUS.size());
System.debug('TM amount of users is ' + territoryManagerUS.size() + 'and the total rate for TM is: ' + totalRateTM); 
 }
```

So by doing this I can separate them and build my calculations between groups. In my requirements we have a small group of US titles, 5 in total, so it will be ok to use this approach.

Please, if anyone have any comments let me know.
Regards and thanks.

Comment: 1) The loop with finalUsers, only grabs data from the first item in the list each iteration.  This will make your data incorrect. 2) Your territoryManagerUS also does the excact same thing, except there is no loop being used here.

Comment: Essentially, I'm saying that your code will give you faulty values on more than a single record.

Comment: Hi dphil. We will never have a mix of users from different countries in a same event, will matter then the way this loop is acting on finalUsers and territoryManagerUS?
From your point of view, should I resolve this anyway? 
What problems can derived from these loops?
Any tips on how can I improve it?
Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I posted an answer that should address these issues.  Could you potentially have US with different titles in the same event?  This would cause the same issue as a mix of countries.

Comment: You right, we will have different US users with different titles on the same event.

Comment: Hello again dphil. Thanks again for your input and help it is much appreciated. I hope you can answer a question I have in regards to the your code. If I have 5 users, US users, on the **finalUsers** list and 2 of them are under the same title, will your code cover that situation? Wouldn't be a solution to have a **userRate** Decimal for each Title? And wouldn't I need to have the amount of US users trough a list.size() per US titles to multiply the amount from each list with the correct rate? 
Please let me know if you can.Thanks

Comment: Yes, my code will cover that situation.  My code covers it.  If you made everything use the Decimal for the rate, then you wouldn't need those extra if statements based off title and you could take those out.

Comment: dphil thanks for your help. It works exactly as you said it would. Can I ask a couple of things more ? :( ... 
I have tried to past the outcome of the **totalRate** to a field on the event page layout in which all calculations are taken place. I haven't been able to accomplish this. Any tips on that? 
And last question. You are mentioning that should be better to use Maps collections for the associations, could you give me an example using this trigger? .. thanks.

Comment: For your trigger, you might need to switch it to a **before** trigger if you are trying to tally up the total rate and place it in an event field.

Comment: The map, would need to store all associated EventRelations to the Id of each Event.  So you would loop through your events, and then tally up all Event relations.  This would allow you to loop through all Events, and then loop through only associated EventRelations.

Comment: Thanks  dphil, I need to do some reading on the map collection. Thanks